Estimate volume between two ellipses if some dimensions are known
I want to estimate the volume between the two ellipses shown in the diagram; the volume is bounded in blue on the sides and by the top ellipse at the top and the bottom ellipse at the bottom.  The diagram shows two views of the same object.  Below is a description of each line:
TEMajA - top ellipse major axis;
BEMajA - bottom ellipse major axis;
TEMinA - top ellipse minor axis;
BEMinA - bottom ellipse minor axis;
MaxH - maximum height (which is on the major axis);
MinH - minimum height (which is on the major axis);
Although not listed as variables the heights between the ellipses are also known for the minor axis.  I know the measurements of each of the  lengths mentioned above.
Clearly, I can get the area for the top and bottom ellipses. But after that I'm not sure how to proceed.

enter image description here



How exactly would you describe the blue wall? Is it part of a cylinder or cone? It's hard to tell from the figures whether MinH and MaxH are vertical or slanted.

In looking at the drawing more precisely the top ellipse is actually a circle with a radius of R.  The bottom ellipse is an ellipse, but it too appears to have a minor axis equal to R.  The major axis is a function of the sin of a collision angle, B, which I am varying from 15 to 90 degrees.  At B = 90, the bottom ellipse is a circle of the same size as the top circle and hence it is easy to get the volume since it is the volume of a cylinder.

Through all values of B, the min height line is pretty much vertical but that is not at all true for the max height.  I've added a picture  for what is almost the x-z plane and for the x-y plane at B = 45 degrees.

For the x-z view the minor axis for the bottom ellipse is a thick dashed line just to the left of the y-axis

Previous comment should be for the x-y view not the x-z view.  Also in my first comment above, it should read sine of a collision angle, B and not sin of a collision angle, B.

Are there software programs that could calculate the volume of a shape if I provide it with certain lengths and measurements?

If you don't mind a slight learning curve, Mathematica has some built-in functions like RegionMeasure that can do what you ask, provided you give your figure a proper parametrization. If you're interested, you can try it free at Wolfram Cloud

Based on the last image, it looks like your region is the part of an elliptic cone between two planes
